# Hacking in additional variables to qmake's Makefile

Tags: qt, gnu-make, qmake

In qmake's Makefile, there's a series of variables that are defined. I'd like to add one more, defined by the .pro file. This section in the Makefile looks like the following:

```
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
```

I'd like to add:

```
TESTARGS     = -xunitxml -o xunitresults.xml
```

A little background as to why: When qmake makes a Makefile using "testcase," it also makes a "check" target that looks like so:

```
check: first
         $(TESTRUNNER) ./$(QMAKE_TARGET) $(TESTARGS)
```

Fully documented [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-common-projects.html#building-a-testcase).

This is really powerful for automated unit testing! Yet, I'd like to set  "TESTARGS" elsewhere in the make file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered that there's a way to add variables, but not the way I expected. I cannot define "TESTARGS" with the following way. What I can do is this, in the .pro file:

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_VARIABLES = FOO
FOO=BAR
```

... But what that renders in the Makefile is this (not quite what I was looking for, but perhaps someone is looking for it):

```
####### Custom Variables
EXPORT_FOO = BAR
```